# how test if a table row with id 'foo' has a certain class?

Tags: rspec, capybara

For my rails 3.0 app, I've got rspec+capybara filling in fields, clicking buttons, and testing for presence of a chunk of text 'anywhere on the page'.

But I cannot find any explanation of how to applying an assertion (has value, contains, or has class) to an element whose ID I know.

For example, I'm trying to test whether a table row whose `id=row_1002` (has class that includes `highlightrow` (perhaps among other classes)

I also want to and also test if the row with `id=row_1002` contains the text "Foobar" anywhere in the row.

Among the many things I tried that throw errors are:

```
find('tr', id: "row_1002")[:class].should include('highlightrow')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
find('td#row_1002')[:class].should include('highlightrow')
```

And for finding the row with the id that contains the text "Foobar" anywhere in the row:

```
find('td#row_1002').text.should include('Foobar')
```